# Не отображаются данные во Vue Router после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Есть файл index.js(представляющий собой экземпляр vue router):

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import List from '../pages/List'
import Zabor from '../pages/Zabor'
import Item from '../pages/Item'

export default new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
      {
        path:'/',
        name: 'list',
        component: List
      },
      {
        path:'/zabor',
        name: 'Zabor',
        component: Zabor
      },
      {
        // парметр id - номер заказа
        path:'/item/:id',
        name: 'Item',
        component: Item,
        props: true
      },
    ]
  })
```

Есть файл Item.vue(Страница представляющая из себя карточку, в которой должны отображаться данные по текущему заказу):

```
<template>
    <div class="listCard">
        <router-link to="/">Вернуться к таблице</router-link>
        <h1>Карточка заказа №{{ id }} от {{ itemInfo.createdAt }}</h1> 
         <div class="info">
            <p>Номер заказа - </p>
            <p>Статус заказа - </p>
            <p>Способ доставки - </p>
             <p>Населенный пункт - </p> 
             <p>Дата последнего изменения - </p> 
        </div>
        
         <hr>
        <p>Cтоимость - <strong></strong></p> 
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            id: String,
        },
        computed: {
            // поиск выбранной записи из массива с заказами по номеру id
            itemInfo() {
                return this.$store.state.orders.find(item => item.shop_id == this.id)
            }
        }

    }
</script>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            id: String,
        },

    }
</script>
```

Здесь входной параметр id передается из компонента ordersTable с помощью конструкции(смотрите ниже), вычисляемое свойство itemInfo возвращает строку данных выбранного заказа

Есть компонент таблицы ordersTable(представляющий из себя таблицу всех заказов), в которой при нажатии на номер заказа происходит переход на страницу карточки выбранного заказа,т.е. в ней отображается вся инфа по заказу. Данную привязку сделал так:

```
<template slot="table-row" slot-scope="props">
            <span v-if="props.column.field == 'shop_id'">
                <span @click="$router.push({ name: 'Item', params: {id: props.row.shop_id, test:'test'}})" class="link">{{props.row.shop_id}}</span>
            </span>
</template>
```

Уточнение! Данные для таблицы прилетают из vuex store, а в store  данные попадают от сервера.

Теперь при выборе какого-либо заказа происходит переход на карточку этого заказа и все необходимые данные отображаются как надо, однако после перезагрузки страницы свойство id отображается как надо, а свойство itemInfo не отображается, в консоль выпадает ошибка якобы  itemInfo это null.
Как передать данные по заказу, чтобы при перезагрузке станицы они отображались.

Дополнение! Пробовал получать данные по заказу в файле Item.vue с помощью get запроса на сервер, все получилось. Однако если данные приходят из store, то после перезагрузки они исчезают.

Comment: Ответ есть в документации vue-router, раздел "Passing Props to Route Components" - к сожалению, на дублирование его тут, у меня не хватает времени.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, у вас поиск в свойстве `itemInfo` начинается до того как эти данные подгружаются с сервера (проблема SPA), поэтому выдает ошибку:

> в консоль выпадает ошибка якобы itemInfo это null

Как вариант, можно скрывать контент карточки товара (при помощи `v-if`) до тех пор пока данные не будут загружены, а вместо него отображать индикатор загрузки.